# How to find the derivative of the Beta function?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

From a standard reference book I found that:

${\partial \over \partial x}\mathrm{B}(x, y) = \mathrm{B}(x, y) \left( {\Gamma'(x) \over \Gamma(x)} - {\Gamma'(x + y) \over \Gamma(x + y)} \right)$.

Currently, I would like to find:

${\partial \over \partial x}\mathrm{B}(1+x, 1-x)$

However, I am unsure how to handle the extra constant inside and am unable to see how the derivative was found. Would this derivative be as simple as just plugging into the equation above? Thanks.

Comment: Use $B(x,y)=\frac{\large\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\large\Gamma(p+q)}$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$B(1+x,1-x)=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)}{\Gamma(2)} \tag 1$$

and

$$\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi x)\Gamma(x)} \tag 2$$

for $0<x<1$.

**SPOILER ALERT**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the answer

> Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ yields $$\begin{align}B(1+x,1-x)&=\frac{\Gamma(1+x)\pi}{\sin(\pi x)\Gamma(x)}\\\\&=\frac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)} \tag 3 \end{align}$$where we used both (i) $\Gamma(2)=1$ and (ii) the [Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition) $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ for the Gamma function.  Now, taking the derivative on both sides of $(3)$ reveals that $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{d B(1+x,1-x)}{dx}=\pi \csc(\pi x)\left(1-(\pi x)\cot (\pi x)\right)}$$And we are done! Note that for $x=0$, we may remove the discontinuity of this expression for the derivative by simply setting the value equal to the limit.  This limit is easily found to be $0$ using standard asymptotic analysis with $\csc(\pi x)\sim \frac{1}{\pi x}$ and $\cot (\pi x)\sim \frac{1-\frac12 (\pi x)^2}{\pi x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's expand the Beta in terms of Gamma-functions:
$$ B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}, $$
so $B(1-x,1+x) = \Gamma(1-x)\Gamma(1+x)/\Gamma(2)$. $\Gamma(2)=1$. Meanwhile,
$$ \Gamma(1-x)\Gamma(1+x) = x \Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x) = x \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi x}} $$
using the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General), so
$$ \frac{d}{dx} B(1-x,1+x) = \pi\csc{\pi x} - \pi^2 x \csc{\pi x} \cot{\pi x} = \pi  \left( 1 - \pi x \cot{\pi x} \right) \csc{\pi x}.$$

Comment: I noticed that for the derivative it is undefined at $x=0$, if $B(1-x, 1+x)$ were something like a moment generating function, would I need another approach?

Comment: You could instead look at the expansion of $z\csc{z}$ for small $z$ (this is known in closed form using the Bernoulli numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Cosecant ) Otherwise it's a matter of taking the limit carefully, with lots of L'Hôpital.

Comment: thanks!!! greatly appreciate the answer!

Comment: I thought I'd give this an up vote since neither of us has received one.

Comment: @Dr.MV Golly, I'd totally forgotten about this one. Good spot.

Comment: @chappers My pleasure.  - Mark